# Install Doom Editing Tools

Tags: 14.04, games

i'm working in a wad for doom and i need **an editor** , a **zdoom based source port** and a **ubuntu version of slade**...

I have windows but slade has a problem on it and the OS *itself* hangs...

Searching did not give me any useful result...

Can anyone help me with this ?

well , if someone doesn't know what is doom (which i don't think so) see [Doom Page on Wikia](http://doom.wikia.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the way :

[Compile SLADE on ubuntu](https://github.com/sirjuddington/SLADE/wiki/Ubuntu-Step-by-Step-Compilation)

[Compile ZDoom on Linux](http://zdoom.org/wiki/Compile_ZDoom_on_Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I use both Slade and Eureka on Ubuntu 18.04.

The current Eureka supports (G)ZDoom features, including rendering of 3D floors and slopes. The 3D mode displays both of these correctly. It does not support UDMF however. It will allow you to write ACS scrpts, but NOT compile them. For this I use Slade. Slade is better for resource editing but does also have a map editor, but this does not display 3d floors. Slade does however compile ACS scripts as long as a BSP builder is configured.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options I've found:

1. Slade - According to their home page, it is Linux compatible.  It requires compiling from source on a Linux box, however.

http://slade.mancubus.net/index.php?page=about

2. Eureka - This is another cross platform Doom editor.  Even better, it is in the repositories, so you should be able to run:

> sudo apt-get install eureka

http://eureka-editor.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help , but :
1. What about the ZDoom based source port ?
2. Is eureka better or slade ?
3. How to compile slade source code on linux ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Eureka's home page does not mention ZDoom, so it probably won't work any of the special features in ZDoom.

As far as compiling from source, I have never really had much luck there.  I did find this guide on compiling Slade from source:

http://slade.mancubus.net/index.php?page=wiki&wikipage=Ubuntu-Step-by-Step-Compilation

I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Well maybe i can try running slade & zdoom via wine ?
Will it test the wad ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to run Slade in WINE.

Comment: What about ZDoom ? it needs a wad to be draged on it...

Comment: You could run ZDoom in WINE too, but it isn't necessary.  Once you've made the WAD with Slade, you can just take that WAD, and run it with ZDoom.

Comment: Yeah you're right. lets try running slade on wine and on error i'll edit this comment...

**EDIT:** Well , no respond from wine...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try to use a thin container utility like firejail, to block and isolate the editor to find out what is going wrong with it.

Firejail blocking works for many kernel functions and network.

I believe it is something to be tried before compiling a new batch, it becomes easier to debug and find out what te problem is.

Here is an excerpt of what firejail is able to intercept/block: seccomp.drop @clock,@cpu-emulation,@debug,@module,@obsolete,@raw-io, @reboot,mbind, migrate_pages,move_pages,set_mempolicy,@swap,acct,add_key,bpf,fanotify_init,io_cancel,io_destroy,io_getevents,io_setup,io_submit,ioprio_set,kcmp,keyctl,mount,name_to_handle_at,nfsservctl,ni_syscall,open_by_handle_at,personality,pivot_root,process_vm_readv,ptrace,remap_file_pages,request_key,setdomainname,sethostname,syslog,umount,umount2,userfaultfd,vhangup,vmsplice